# Why Chrome ignors onClick action?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, radio-button

I got some piece of HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" onClick="rdbtn()" value="1" data-role="admin" data-isprm="true">
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" onClick="rdbtn()" value="2" data-role="admin" data-isprm="false">
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" onClick="rdbtn()" value="3" data-role="admin" data-isprm="true">

<a id='MANAGE_SYMBOLS' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='nosel();' class='actionButton'>Manage Symbols</a><br/><br/>
<a id='EDIT_COUNTRY' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='nosel();' class='thickbox actionButton'>Edit Country</a><br/><br/>
<a id='LOAD_PARTNERS' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='nosel();' class='thickbox actionButton'>Import Distributors</a><br/>

<input class="MANAGE_SYMBOLS" type="hidden" value="fetchSymbols.action?action=edit&height=300&width=400&idCountry=COUNTRY_ID">
<input class="EDIT_COUNTRY" type="hidden" value="editCountry.action?action=edit&height=550&width=600&id=COUNTRY_ID">
<input class="LOAD_PARTNERS" type="hidden" value="addDistributors.action?countryId=COUNTRY_ID&height=400&width=350">

<a class="MANAGE_SYMBOLS" href="#"/>
<a class="EDIT_COUNTRY" href="#"/>
<a class="LOAD_PARTNERS" href="#"/>
```

I also wrote a script:

```
function rdbtn(){
 $('input[name="radioBtn"]').change(function(){
    var url = "";
    var radioVal = $(this).val();
    var radioPRM = $('input[name="radioBtn"]:checked').data('isprm');
    var role = $('input[name="radioBtn"]:checked').data('role');

    url = $('input[class="MANAGE_SYMBOLS"]').val();
    url = url.replace('COUNTRY_ID',radioVal);
    if (!radioPRM) {
        document.getElementById('MANAGE_SYMBOLS').href = url;
        document.getElementById('MANAGE_SYMBOLS').onclick = '';
        document.getElementById('MANAGE_SYMBOLS').style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('MANAGE_SYMBOLS').style.display = 'none';
    }

    url = $('input[class="EDIT_COUNTRY"]').val();
    url = url.replace('COUNTRY_ID',radioVal);
    document.getElementById('EDIT_COUNTRY').href = url;
    document.getElementById('EDIT_COUNTRY').onclick = '';

    url = $('input[class="LOAD_PARTNERS"]').val();
    url = url.replace('COUNTRY_ID',radioVal);
    document.getElementById('LOAD_PARTNERS').href = url;
    document.getElementById('LOAD_PARTNERS').onclick = '';
    document.getElementById('LOAD_PARTNERS').style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.getElementById('LOAD_DISTRIBUTORS').style.display = 'none';
}
```

I would like to know why this is working as expected on Firefox and IE - but when I select radio button in Chrome, it behaves like onChange event on radio button (first select does nothing, but second select works as expected).As we can see, it has onClick="rdbtn()" event specified.

Can you suggest how to fix that?

Comment: Any error messages in the console? or does it silently ignore it? (Perhaps you could setup a fiddle?)

Comment: Sorry my solution didn't help. Might I ask, why do you mix jQuery and native JS ? I would not put the `.change` into a function that is called when something is clicked, I'd put it into an `$(document).ready();` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply write complete code in jQuery instead of inline javascript:

```
$('input[name="radioBtn"]').change(function () {
    var url = "";
    var radioVal = $(this).val();
    var radioPRM = $('input[name="radioBtn"]:checked').data('isprm');
    var role = $('input[name="radioBtn"]:checked').data('role');
    url = $('input[class="MANAGE_SYMBOLS"]').val();
    url = url.replace('COUNTRY_ID', radioVal);
    if (!radioPRM) {
        $('#MANAGE_SYMBOLS').attr('href', url);
        $('#MANAGE_SYMBOLS').off('click');
        $('#MANAGE_SYMBOLS').css('display', 'inline-block');
    } else {
        $('#MANAGE_SYMBOLS').hide();
    }
    url = $('input[class="EDIT_COUNTRY"]').val();
    url = url.replace('COUNTRY_ID', radioVal);
    $('#EDIT_COUNTRY').attr('href', url);
    $('#EDIT_COUNTRY').off('click');
    url = $('input[class="LOAD_PARTNERS"]').val();
    url = url.replace('COUNTRY_ID', radioVal);
    $('#LOAD_PARTNERS').attr('href', url);
    $('#LOAD_PARTNERS').off('click');
    $('#LOAD_PARTNERS').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('#LOAD_DISTRIBUTORS').hide();
});
```

The problem with your code was that you were just calling the `function rdbtn` onclick which further binds the change events.
Instead you could have remove the `change` event binding and passed `this` in `onclick="rdbtn(this)"` and used it in your rdbtn code

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/149/

I removed inline js code. Put the code inside a document.ready or wrap it in a function and call it on document.ready.

Comment: Perfect! Works fine but this line does not do anything: $('#LOAD_PARTNERS').off('click');. I changed it to $('#LOAD_PARTNERS').attr('onclick', ''); is that alright?

Comment: that line actually removes the click handler. So, if you want to remove the click functionality from the element, then you need to use that line. However, adding attr('onclick','') will be of no use. It's better to use jquery custom function for the purpose. You can refer die function of jquery for more details.